# How to make a class run constantly

Tags: java, lwjgl

I made a class that controls all the keys for my game in lwjgl using such method:

```
        if (Keyboard.isKeyDown(Keyboard.KEY_A)) {

            System.out.println(".....");
        }
```

Except on a much larger scale. My problem occurs that when this class is called it only runs through once so the only way to see the effect of the code is to have a thumb spasm on the A button as the game starts up...

My code:

```
public class KeyBindings {

    public static void run() {

        try {

            Keyboard.create();

        } catch (LWJGLException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        if (Keyboard.isKeyDown(Keyboard.KEY_F1)) {

            System.out.println(".............................");
        }
   }
```

And then I call `KeyBindings.run();` from another class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to options:

- Poll key states.
- React to asynchronous key events.

To implement the first option you should schedule a Timer task whereas to implement the second option, which is the best, you could use [key-listeners](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/keylistener.html).

This piece of code can help you to understand how to schedule a repetitive task using Timers:

```
Timer t = new Timer();
long period = 5*60*1000; //For example 5 minutes
long delay = 1*60*1000; //For example 1 minute
t.schedule(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
               //To do: Your code to be repeated each period ms
            }
        }, delay, period);
```

You can include this code into your class:

```
public class KeyBindings {

    private Timer t;

    KeyBindings() {
        t = new Timer();
        long period = 5*60*1000; //For example 0.5 seconds
        long delay = period;
        t.schedule(new TimerTask() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                   run();
                }
            }, delay, period);
    }

    public static void run() {

        try {

            Keyboard.create();

        } catch (LWJGLException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        if (Keyboard.isKeyDown(Keyboard.KEY_F1)) {

            System.out.println(".............................");
        }
   }

}
```

You should consider stopping the Timer thread when you have finished listening your keyboard input. Another option, if your application has to poll keyboard state all over its execution, is to mark your Timer as [daemon](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#setDaemon%28boolean%29) so it won´t prevent the application to finish.

Comment: Yes I have dabbled in KeyListeners but I also recently read about Timers so could you elaborate on those

Comment: @FeatheredOrcian I have wrote a little example for you. I hope it helps you.

Comment: @FeatheredOrcian http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#setDaemon(boolean) java.lang.Thread

Comment: @FeatheredOrcian I am sorry, I did paste the wrong link/class: java.util.Timer http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html

Comment: That is funny because for 5 minutes i was stumped as to why you posted that.

Answer (score 0):

Repeat logic of keys recognition in a loop.

```
public class KeyBindings {
    private volatile boolean shoutDown;

    public void setShoutDown(boolean shoutDown) {
        this.shoutDown = shoutDown;
    }

    public static void run() {

        try {

            Keyboard.create();

        } catch (LWJGLException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        while (!shutDown) {
            if (Keyboard.isKeyDown(Keyboard.KEY_F1)) {
                System.out.println(".............................");
            }
        }
    }
```

}

Comment: I tried something similar to this and it worked until the point where it continuously outputed ............